# Customize Tax amount in "woocommerce_package_rates" hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax

I recently tried to modify all my shipping rates with hook to apply discount.

Here's my code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates' );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( ! wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'silver' ) ) { return $rates; }
    $discount_amount = 30; // 30%

    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
        $rates[$key]->cost = $rates[$key]->cost - ( $rates[$key]->cost * ( $discount_amount/100 ) );
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

But one more step is the tax ! I got wrong tax.
For example I have my shipping rate who cost `3$`. With the discount, it's now `2,10$`.

I buy one item for `2$` and the shipping `2.10$`.
I got 1$ for the tax (as the 3$ shipping cost. look like he doesn't take the changes) and normally it's `0.82$`.

What do I need to get the correct tax calculation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated: add tax cost calculation, and removed some typos.

There is some little errors on your code and you have missed the tax calculation discount. I have revisited your code a bit, you should try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'conditional_shipping_discount', 10, 2 );
function conditional_shipping_discount( $rates, $packages ) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( ! wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'silver' ) ) return $rates;

    $percent = 30; // 30%
    $discount = 1 - ($percent / 100);

    foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // Get original cost
        $original_cost = $rates[$rate_id]->cost;
        // Calculate the discounted rate cost
        $new_cost = $original_cost * $discount;
        // Set the discounted rate cost
        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = number_format($new_cost, 2);
        // calculate the conversion rate (for taxes)
        $conversion_rate = $new_cost / $original_cost;

        // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
        $taxes = array();
        foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
            if( $tax > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                // set the new line tax cost in the taxes array
                $taxes[$key] = number_format( $tax * $conversion_rate, 2 );
            }
        }
        // Set the new taxes costs
        $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

> **You should need to refresh the shipping caches:**

1. First this code is already saved on your function.php file.
2. In Shipping settings, enter in a Shipping Zone and disable a **Shipping Method** and "save". Then re-enable that **Shipping Method** and "save". **You are done.**

Comment: Ohh nice one ! Thanks a lot @LoicTheAztec !! Perfecly what I needed

Comment: I don't understand, I use your answer and this time the tax calculation doesn't work. Maybe this code has conflict with something ?

Comment: @Efbi I have updated the code around the tax calculation

Comment: Hi somes issues appeared, 1/ The rates parts hide the price 2/ when I put the taxes part, I have blank page

Comment: Oups, it's just a ";" missed. Thanks it works ! I keep the previous version because it hide the price and adapt it

Comment: A little late, but why not just use $rate_values->taxes = $taxes; instead of $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes?

Answer (score 0):

Below code @LoicTheAztec without mistakes:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'conditional_shipping_discount', 10, 2 );
    function conditional_shipping_discount( $rates, $packages ) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( ! wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'silver' ) ) return $rates;

    $percent = 30; // 30%
    $discount = 1 - ($percent / 100);

    foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate_values ) {
        // Get original cost
        $original_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
        // Calculate the discounted rate cost
        $new_cost = $original_cost * $discount;
        // Set the discounted rate cost
        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = number_format($new_cost, 2);
        // calculate the conversion rate (for taxes)
        $conversion_rate = $new_cost / $original_cost;

        // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
        $taxes = array();
        foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
            if( $tax > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                // set the new line tax cost in the taxes array
                $taxes[$key] = number_format( $tax * $conversion_rate, 2 );
            }
        }
        // Set the new taxes costs
        $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the answers above is that you're calculating the tax based on the calculations already made for the original cost. What if, for example, a plugin is calculating the tax based on the shipping cost? For example, 10% if $100 or above, 20% if $200 or above, 0% if less than $100.

If the original cost was $150 and you're applying a $60 discount, the discounted cost would be $90 and no tax would apply in the aforementioned scenario. So we need a way to modify the cost **before the tax is calculated**. This way we don't have to recalculate the tax ourselves and we reduce bugs like the example in the first paragraph.

For one of my plugins I'm using the `woocommerce_shipping_method_add_rate_args` filter, which is called by \WC_Shipping_Method::add_rate(). This method is called everytime a \WC_Shipping_Method instance adds a rate.

This filter will accept an array as its first argument, which is the rate data. This array has a 'cost' entry which is what we want to modify. Keep in mind that this can be a scalar (apparently, a numeric string) or an array. Just check if it's an array when dealing with this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_method_add_rate_args', function(array $rateArguments) : array {
     // Total up the cost. Taken from the WooCommerce source code. woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-shipping-method.php
     $totalCost = is_array( $rateArguments['cost'] ) ? array_sum( $rateArguments['cost'] ) : $rateArguments['cost'];

     $rateArguments['cost'] = 'here the final cost';
            
     return $rateArguments; 
});
```