# add_filter issue in custom plugin file for WooCommerce shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

here's my custom plugin code :

```
class Class_name
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( is_admin() ) {

            //Custom admin menu
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this,'custom_submenu_page'));


            add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', array($this , 'conditional_shipping', 10, 2 ));

        }
    }
function conditional_shipping( $rates, $packages ) {
    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:32'] ) ) {
    // Set the cost to $100
    $rates['flat_rate:32']->cost = 100;
}
    return $rates;
}



}


new Class_name();
```

I'm triying to use this filter but he doesn't work. Nothing happens in the front end. I don't know where is the error.

It's not like that I should use the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** related to tax calculation on the Shipping Method.

There is some mistakes in your code like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', array( $this , 'conditional_shipping', 10, 2 ) );
```

… that should be instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', array( $this , 'conditional_shipping' ), 10, 2 );
```

Or at the end of your code:

```
new Class_name();
```

… that should be instead:

```
$GLOBALS['class_name'] = new Class_name();
```

So you should try something like this complete code *(empty the cart before)*:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

if ( ! class_exists( 'Class_Name' ) ) {

    class Class_Name {

        public function __construct() {
            //Custom admin menu
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this,'custom_submenu_page'));
            
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', array( $this , 'conditional_shipping' ), 10, 2 );
        }

        public function conditional_shipping( $rates, $package ) {
            // HERE Defined Method rate ID
            $rate_key = 'flat_rate:32';
            
            // HERE Define New cost
            $new_cost = 100;
            
            ## -- 1. Set the rate cost -- ##

            if ( isset( $rates[$rate_key] ) ){
                // Get original cost
                $original_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
                // Set the new cost
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = number_format($new_cost, 2);
                // calculate the conversion rate (for taxes)
                $conversion_rate = $new_cost / $original_cost;
            }
            
            ## -- 2. Taxes rate cost calculation (if enabled) -- ##
            
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    // set the new line tax cost in the array
                    $taxes[$key] = number_format($tax * $conversion_rate, 2);
                }
            }
            // Set the new taxes costs
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            
            ## -- Return new costs -- ##
            return $rates;
        }
    }
    $GLOBALS['class_name'] = new Class_Name();
}
```

This code goes in a plugin file. It is tested and works.

> You may need to **refresh shipping methods**:
>
> Go to WooCommerce shipping settings and in the related shipping zone for your "Flat rate", disable / save and re-enable / save the corresponding "flat rate".

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec ! Thanks for the answer, I try each changes one by one to be sure, and you're right the issue was causing by the ")". Also thanks for the others correction

Comment: But I don't understand a thin, I use your answer from previous questions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038622/customize-tax-amount-in-woocommerce-package-rates-hook) and this time the tax calculation doesn't work.

Comment: @Efbi Updated and tested. It works for taxes too. Try it.